# How to gzip file in place replacement Java

Tags: java, apache, compression, gzip

I have a .xlsx file (or any file) which I would like to gzip. I am able to gzip the file but now I have the problem of trying to do this in place. Meaning to replace the original file with the gzipped version of the file.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File file = new File("test.xlsx");
    File gfile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath()+".gz");

    if(!file.exists()) {
        System.err.println("Input tax file did not exist!");
    }

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(gfile);
    GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
    gzipReplace(fis, gos);
}



private static void gzipReplace(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    int oneByte;
    try {
        while( (oneByte = is.read()) != -1 ) {
            os.write(oneByte);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
}
```

How can I do an in-place replacement of an uncompressed file with a gzipped one?

Comment: I should think that since your using the text file to create a gzip file of it, you simply can't overwrite it right away but I'm sure what you can do is once the compression has "successfully" completed simply move or delete the text file.

Comment: I want it to be generic to work with any file type, txt was just an example. I will update the details to my question. I will be doing this for about 2 million files. So space will be a concern as the process runs, do doing an in place replacement will be a better solution and faster than adding a procedure to delete the original file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `File.delete()` on the original file after *successful* compression and writing of the gzip file.

You must be very careful to not delete the original file until you are certain that the new compressed file was successfully written and closed. Otherwise you are setting yourself up to lose data.

Comment: so there is no easy way to do a in place file replacement?

Comment: No, there is no easy way. Since you are doing this for millions of files, then you will only be taking up the space of _one_ additional file at each step as its compressed and uncompressed forms are temporarily on the disk at the same time. Assuming that the files are compressible, you will be reducing the amount of disk space used at every step.

Comment: If on the other hand you were trying to compress one giant file that takes up most of your disk space, _then_ it would make sense to go to the effort of overwriting the uncompressed file with compressed data as you go along, and truncating the resulting file at the end. That would have to be done very carefully to avoid overwriting uncompressed data not yet compressed when the data expands some due to incompressibility. You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12412863/1180620) for how that is done in memory, which can be rewritten to do the same thing in the file system instead.